# How to access data in old DOS RapidFile data files

Tags: database, export, legacy-database

I need to get access to some data that is stored in an old DOS format. Specifically using Ashton-Tate's RapidFile format.

Does anyone know if there are ADO drivers or any other more "modern" data access technology that will enable me to read the data?

Answer (score 1):

I did not find any ODBC drivers for RapidFile, but I did find a link to this company that *might* be able to help you out.  http://www.rapidfile.co.uk/